# Community user unable to view attachment

Tags: insufficient-privileges

I need some help in resolving this problem . I have spent many hours troubleshooting this with no luck.

**Issue:**
We have a community user who is able to attach and delete attachments to **Contact** object but when they try to view the attachment they get insufficient privileges.

**Object Permission:** They have read / write / create access on both account and contact.

**Sharing Setting**:

Internal Access is Public Read/Write on Accounts and Contact is Controlled by Parent

External Access is Private for accounts and contact is controlled by Parent.

We are using Attachment object and **Customer Community Plus** Login User Licenses. The attachment is created via Code

Does anyone know what can be causing a problem here . Any help wold be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your post to include more details and clarifications:  Are you using Customer Community or Partner Community licenses?  What are your organization-wide defaults for sharing on these objects?  Are you using the old Attachment object or the newer Files object?

Comment: Hi David Cheng I have edited my post to include more info , Thank you for looking into this for me

Comment: Are those attachments or Salesforce files? Just confirming?

Comment: I am attaching attachments on contact object through code .

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I am attaching attachments on contact object through code

Comment: Hi @DavidCheng Hi David Cheng I have edited my post to include more info , Thank you for looking into this for me –

Answer (score 1):

Please enable Notes and Attachments to Community users.
From setup, enter Community Settings in the Quick Find, then select Communities Settings.
Select Lets customer users access notes and attachments.
Click Save.